# .net 7.0 and Maui blazor, app working in Debug mode but not functioning in release

Tags: android, blazor, apk, maui, visual-studio-2022

I'm developing a MAUI Blazor app with VS2022, destined tò Android API33, tested as working in Debug mode on the Pixel 5 emulator and so on my physical device Samsung S22 attached via USB for deployment.
When trying tò distribute It (release mode), in any combination (apk _ aab / internal version, alpha, beta ...) there's no way to see It working.
After the splashscreen the app exits and no way tò find any log info (even I injected a Serilog logger).
Any ideas....?

I would like to find a way to distribute It in release version.
Tried as ADHOC distribution (apk) and also by Google Play Console (aab with signed filee).
The Life of the app ends After the splashscreen.

Comment: Hello and thanks a lot for your help. Unfortunately I've had yet seen the related issue and yet tried the solution but the problem.
With that solutio, now the app in debug mode works as soon as it is launched via player in VS2022 but I trying to launch it  (both on the emultaor and on the physical device), it behaves like in release mode. Splashscreen and immediate exit. Until some days ago, working on this app, I could share the generated debug apk with my colleauges as they could install it - working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can create a linker in ILLink.Descriptors.xml file like this.

```
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="Mono.Android">
        <type fullname="Android.Runtime.InputStreamAdapter" preserve="methods" />
        <type fullname="Android.Runtime.InputStreamInvoker" preserve="methods" />
    </assembly>
</linker>
```

Put this in your .csproj as well:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="ILLink.Descriptors.xml">
  <LogicalName>ILLink.Descriptors.xml</LogicalName>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

Here is the related issue [[Bug] Maui-Blazor Project Template crashes in Release Mode](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2246) on the GitHub you can refer to.